# Where does the video of Picard with a hat and cane on the bridge of the Enterprise come from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the awesome [Picard Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6oUz1v17Uo), there are clips from another video where Picard is dancing with a hat and cane on the bridge of the Enterprise.

[image: Picard Video]

I've never been able to figure out where this video comes from, I'm pretty sure it's not in any TNG episode.

Does anyone know the original source of the Picard hat and cane video?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - thx for the screenshot

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Patrick Stewart Alphabet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjNKyoRudOQ)

That indicates it's a DVD extra for Season 5.  And [this](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Talk:TNG_Season_5_DVD) confirms.

Comment: This is an awesome tribute to Gene Roddenbury on the Season 5 DVD :)